# Override default value of null conditional operator

Tags: c#, .net

Following is a very simple code

```
   public static void Main()
    {
        string mode = null;
        string abc = mode?.ToLower();
        if(abc == "cs")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not null");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(abc);
    }
```

I'm getting an empty string in the variable *abc*. I want to customize the return value for **?.** operator. How can I do that ?

Comment: "I want to customize the default value(which in this case is an empty string)" - no it's not, it's a null reference.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah !! updated the question body.

Comment: Another update would be useful, as you're *not* getting an empty string in `abc`.

Answer (score 8):

For `null` you could use the [null conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) with [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) which would give you a default value;

```
string abc = mode?.ToLower() ?? "somethingelse";
```

Or you could write you own *extension method*, add pepper and salt to taste

```
public static string DefaultIfEmpty(this string str, string defaultValue, bool considerWhiteSpaceIsEmpty = false)
   => (considerWhiteSpaceIsEmpty ? string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) : string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) ? defaultValue : str;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify `?` - ToLower() is not being evaluated if your string is null.

You can null-coalesque:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string mode = null;
        string abc = (mode ?? "BIG").ToLower(); 
        if (abc == "cs")  // abc is "big" here
        {
            Console.WriteLine("not null");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(abc);
    }
}
```

Comment: @aloisdg now it works. and `mode` is not empty - it is null.